# Why foreach loop gives the wrong sum in this situation?

Tags: java

```java
public class Kata {
    public static int squareSum(int[] n) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i : n) {
            sum += n[i] * n[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

If array is `{1,2,2}` squareSum should be `9`, however it gives `12`.

At the same moment, this code gives our the right answer `9`.

```java
public class Kata {
    public static int squareSum(int[] n) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
            sum += n[i] * n[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Why? How does it work?

Comment: The first example uses a foreach loop. Meaning it iterates over the members of the array. More specifically, i is not 0,1,2, but rather 1, 2, 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first code:

```java
public class Kata {
    public static int squareSum(int[] n) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i : n) {
            sum += n[i] * n[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

You are **using the values as index**, so the iterations will be:

1. `i = 1` -> `n[i] = 2`
2. `i = 2` -> `n[i] = 2`
3. `i = 2` -> `n[i] = 2`

In the second code:

```java
public class Kata {
    public static int squareSum(int[] n) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
            sum += n[i] * n[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Works because you are **correctly iterating over the indexes**, so the iterations will be:

1. `i = 0` -> `n[i] = 1`
2. `i = 1` -> `n[i] = 2`
3. `i = 2` -> `n[i] = 2`

If you want to use a *For-Each Loop*, you can do it this way:

```java
public class Kata {
    public static int squareSum(int[] n) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int value : n) {
            sum += value * value;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

#### Edit:

In [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77362247/21144042) you asked:

> why the result of wrong code is 12 instead of exception?

Well, you have the list `{1,2,2}`, so the indexes will be:

- Index: `0` -> Value: `1`
- Index: `1` -> Value: `2`
- Index: `2` -> Value: `2`

It don't throw an exception because the array actually have the indexes `1`, `2` and `2`.

But if you use `{1,2,3}`, it will throw a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because the array don't have the index `3`.

Answer (score 1):

> *"Why foreach loop gives the wrong sum in this situation? ..."*

Use *i*, not *n[i]*.

```java
int sum = 0;
for (int i : n) sum += i * i;
return sum;
```

Or, use a *[stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html)*.

```java
return IntStream.of(n).map(x -> x * x).sum();
```

```java
return IntStream.of(n).reduce((a, b) -> a + (b * b)).getAsInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

When using foreach loop we have to use `n` instead of `n[i]`.

```java
sum += n * n;
```

However, I still don t understand why the result of wrong code is `12` instead of an exception?

Comment: I explained in my answer, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

In first scenario the sum must be `sum+= i * i`.Instead it's `n[i] * n[i]`, which results in accessing element based on index.